# Is there a way to prevent the warning message from displaying on a Chrome extension installation

Tags: security, google-chrome, installation, google-chrome-extension

When you install an extension to the Google Chrome browser from Chrome's website, the installation procedure pops up instantly, without warning. ([Chrome's website](https://chrome.google.com))

When you install an extension from any other website, there is a warning message: "Extensions, apps, and themes can harm your computer. Are you sure you want to continue?"

My extension is trusted and displayed on Chrome's website, but is there a way to remove this scary warning from my website's  download page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself there is no way to do this because chrome just checks if the extension install is launched from its own website.

For people wondering what I eventually did (if there will ever be) :

As soon as the user clicks on the install button, I hide the document with an 80% opaque layer and show a box pointing where to click to continue the installation.